# What does slow your role mean and is it role or roll?

Tags: meaning

Can someone please help me to clear this up in this statement:

> Should it be **role** or **roll** and what is the meaning and/or
>   origin of it.

Comment: Please give us the source and full quote.

Comment: I'm commenting as a reviewer because your question is at risk of being closed. It is difficult to answer your question because it doesn't include enough information. Users need to know where this statement occurred, including the context around it, in order to be able to answer it. Please give as much information about it as you can in order to get a good answer. You can browse the site and look at other questions with upvotes to get examples of what a good question looks like.

Answer (score 1):

"Slow your roll" is a slang expression that roughly means to "calm down" or "relax." It is commonly associated with the lingo of American "gangsta" culture. This culture has a distinctive slang vocabulary and manner of speech, which is sometimes even considered its own dialect. This expression is not offensive, but due to its strong cultural association I would advise English learners not to use it. You can say "calm down" instead with exactly the same meaning.

I haven't been able to discover the origin of the expression. A web search suggests it dates back at least to the mid-1990s and possibly earlier. This is only speculation on my part, but I would guess that the meaning is an allusion to rolling dice, as in a board game, evoking the idea of an overly excited player throwing the dice recklessly.